# Replacing only the first occurrence of a shortcode PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, shortcode

I am modifying a CMS that has shortcodes.  The shortcodes look like this

```
[code]Total_Public_Activities id=1 type=table[/code]
```

A CMS page could have multiple shortcodes in it.  A user might accidentally use the same shortcode more than once.  In my situation, using the same shortcode more than once caused the second item to not appear and produced a JavaScript error.  The reason for this was that the CMS was using

```
str_replace( $searchStr, $myContent, $getCmsPage->page_content );
```

This caused duplicate content elements like two  elements to be placed on the page.  The JavaScript had issues with that.  I changed that line to use preg_replace.

```
preg_replace( $escapedSearchPattern, $myContent, $getCmsPage->page_content );
```

My $escapedSearchPattern looks like:

```
    /\[code\]Total_Public_Activities id=1 type=table\[\/code\]/
```

However, preg_replace seems to modify the $myContent replacement content string when it inserts it into the page_content.  In one instance, I had a datatables.js table and in each of the  elements of one row was placed the $searchStr (i.e. the shortcode).  Why does preg_replace not work as expected?  How can I just replace the first instance of a shortcode using PHP?

Comment: You can set a limit as the forth parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Is this a custom CMS or an existing product?

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle: You should put this as an answer!

Comment: I am not sure I understand - do you mean, how to only replace the Total_Public_Activities and not the id=1...

Comment: Can you provide a full input string that causes a problem, show how your method mangles it, and show your required output?  I'm sure we can help you if you give us enough information to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a limit as the forth parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
preg_replace( $escapedSearchPattern, $myContent, $getCmsPage->page_content, 1 );
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue with preg_replace modifying the replacement content.